# Lights in swimming pool not working

Tags: wiring

I have a light switch feeding two lights in my swimming pool. The lights won't come work when the light switch is closed. When in the closed position I get 110v across the line and load terminals. What does this indicate?

Answer (score 2):

If you get power across the 2 terminals when the switch is "on" (closed), it means your switch has failed and needs to be replaced. Of course be sure to turn off the power before replacing and if this is a switch outdoors, be sure to get a high quality replacement and appropriate coverings for the code in your area.

EDIT--additional info: To test, with the power off you could disconnect the switch, wire nut the 2 wires together, turn the power back on and see if your pool lights work then.  Have you checked to see if they are simply burned out?

Comment: There should be a step down transformer somewhere, check the voltage there too. There might also be a mini-breaker for the light circuit.

Comment: Good point, JACK! If the test I suggested doesn't diagnose the problem, your suggestion is a great one.